# Getting Mismatched certification error in oozie workflow while connecting to MIS in exchange server?

Tags: java, ssl

I am running oozie workflow for connecting to exchange server and accessing the database 
but i am getting following error of certification.

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. sun.security.validato.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
```

I have executed the command to see the available certificates that is showing some 44 entries in /home/jdk/jre/security/cacerts.

Comment: What Java version are you using, and has it been altered? No vanilla Sun^WOracle JDK has shipped with that few certs in cacerts for 5 years at least. Anyway, you need to know what CA root cert and possibly chain certs the server is using to accurately identify the problem. The easiest way is if you have or get openssl; run `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port`, as soon as it connects type your EOF character (^Z on Windows, usually ^D on Unix) or Q return, and look near the beginning of the output for `Certificate chain:` and several numbered pairs of lines. ...

Comment: ... Also note that JRE/lib/security/cacerts is the *default* trustore for Java SSL connections, but it is overridden by jssecacerts if that is present, and either of those can be overridden by system properties or by the code you are running; are you sure neither of those is done?